# HTML-style table definition?

Tags: tables

Is there any LaTeX environment which lets you express a table in a similar logical fashion to HTML or MediaWiki tables?

- Size defined by the number of cells found, rather than pre-specified in the table definition.
- Automatically puts lines in the right places without having to specify each line individually.
- Auto-scales columns to balance how much text each one has while fitting in page width.
- Cell entries have optional rowspan or colspan attribute.
- Word-wrap available in each cell.

Comment: more or less `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|*{40}{L|}` does most of that (`tabulary` package)

Comment: This is exactly how the ConTeXt [TABLE](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE) macros work. Like CSS, you can also specify table styling separately from the table content.

Comment: tabulary doesn't seem to handle rowspan very well (at all?) especially if you want lines around each cell -  \cline{2-6} only works if you keep track of which areas weren't covered by a rowspanned cell.

Answer (score 7):

Like HTML+CSS, the new LaTeX3 package `tabularray` provides a way to specify table styles separately from the table contents. `Tabularray` satisfies the above requirements, except the third point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
 hlines = {white},
 vlines = {white},
 columns = {co=1},
 cell{1,6}{odd} = {teal7},
 cell{1,6}{even} = {green7},
 cell{2,4}{1,4} = {red7},
 cell{3,5}{1,4} = {purple7},
 cell{2}{2} = {r=4,c=2}{c,azure7},
}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   & Delta   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     & Theta   \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu      \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron & Pi      \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     & Upsilon \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     & Omega   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```